# Messages between Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have body:text content:text sender_id:integer receiver_id:integer in message table

I have this in user model:

```
   has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
   has_many :received_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "receiver_id"
```

I have this in message model:

```
   belongs_to :sender, :class_name=>"User", :foreign_key=>"sender_id"
   belongs_to :receiver, :class_name=>"User", :foreign_key=>"receiver_id"
```

After logging while you are viewing the other user's profile (I mean this link in users view).

I call new message like this:

```
  <%= link_to "Send a Message",{:controller=>"messages",:action=>"new"}%>
```

I have these codes in messages_controller:

```
 def new
  @message = current_user.sent_messages.build
   end

def create
@message = current_user.sent_messages.build(params[:message])
  if @message.save
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully created message."
  redirect_to root_url
else
  render :action => 'new'
 end
 end
#.....
```

Also I have these codes in views\messages\new.html.erb

```
 <% form_for @message do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
 <%= f.label :body %><br />
 <%= f.text_field :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
 <%= f.label :content %><br />
 <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </p>
 <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
  <% end %>
```

After clicking link I fill body and text then submit. Everything is saved but receiver_id value is null. I tried many things to do but I couldn't save receiver_id

For ex: I set link like that:

```
  <%= link_to "Send a Message",{:controller=>"messages",:action=>"new",
   :receiver_id=>@user.id}%>
```

It sends the user id which I want and I can get this value with params but the problem is I couldn't find a way to save this value to database while saving the others.

Answer (score 0):

Passing `receiver_id` in the params just gives the `new` method access to it. You'll need to access and store `params[:receiver_id]` somewhere in your `new` method.

Answer (score 0):

Lol I found I call new message like I mentioned before

```
 <%= link_to "Send a Message",{:controller=>"messages",:action=>"new",
 :receiver_id=>@user}%>
```

then new method will be like that in message model

```
 def new
 @message =current_user.sent_messages.build(:receiver_id=>params[:receiver_id])
  end
```

And the simplest thing(actual it's the big problem for me :)) in views/messages/new.html.erb add this line in form_for

```
 <%= f.hidden_field :receiver_id  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
class MessagesController
   def new
     @message = current_user.sent_messages.build :receiver_id => params[:receiver_id]
   end    
end
```

personally I like to use nested routes in the url like so

domain/users/123/messages/new

then you can do

```
link_to "Send a message", new_user_message( @user )
```

so your controller would say

```
class MessagesController
   def new
     @message = current_user.sent_messages.build :receiver_id => params[:user_id]
   end    
end
```