# Creating a nested_resource that belongs to two instances of same model (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a message model in which a message belongs to two Users, the Sender and the Recipient.  Users, likewise, will have_many Messages as Sent_Messages and Received_Messages.

I'm running into trouble when I try to create a new email.  My form shows fine, but then when I attempt to save, I get different errors (depending on what attempt at a solution I've most recently tried currently "User expected, got string").

My models and relavent controller defs are as follows:

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => 'sender_id' 
    has_many :received_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
    ...
end
```

Message.rb

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
   belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User'
   ...
end
```

Message_Controller.rb
    before_filter :get_user

```
...

def new
  @message = @user.sent_messages.build
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @message }
  end
end

def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @message.save
      format.html { redirect_to @message, notice: 'Message was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @message, status: :created, location: @message }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

...

private

  def get_user
 @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end
```

I recognize that there is something fundamentally wrong with how I'm trying this, but I'm fairly new to rails and all related questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904272/messages-between-users?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698081/node-expected-got-string)) don't seem to have any answers that help me.

**edit:**

_form:

```
<%= form_for([@user, @message]) do |f| %>
    ...
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :recipient %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :recipient %>
    </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :subject %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :subject %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post the form?

Comment: d_ethier: thanks for asking about that.  I can see now that the error is in the  <%= f.text_field :recipient %> line.  Eventually, I'll probably want to auto-populate this based on what page a user creates a new message from, but for prototyping I'll just want to enter in IDs.  Is there a clean way to do this through the form? Or, should this be done through the controller?  Keeping in mind eventual plans (creating messages from user pages), is one way better?

Comment: A bit of a different question but you could use a hidden field in the form that will be passed to the controller in the same params hash as the other values. With that, you could pass it either a value from the controller or in the view itself.